# Regarding the working of microprocessor when the computer gets started

Tags: microprocessors

When microprocessor gets started, how does it know that its program counter (PC) has to be loaded with address FFFF0h?  If it's pre-programmed then please let me know that how is it programmed to fetch that address.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the microprocessor.  Most microprocessors reset the program counter to zero when the reset pin is activated.  Either way it's built into the firmware (if appropriate) or circuitry (otherwise) of the processor.